# Connect 2 BGA pins before soldering IC?

Tags: pcb, soldering, bga, rework

My first thought was it's not possible but I need a method that could potentially work, just for testing purposes. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I forgot to breakout one BGA pin that I need for testing. However, the pin adjacent to it is broken out and I could use that if I could somehow short the 2 pins together on the bare board and then solder the BGA. A short to the pin itself or to the via.

I was thinking of making a cut from pin to pin or pin to via and filling the space with a thin line of conductive paste, either solder paste or conductive epoxy?

[image]

Comment: What's your BGA ball pitch?

Comment: BGA ball pitch is 0.8mm

Comment: Idea: Using a high melting point solder alloy, solder-bridge the two BGA balls on the IC that you want to short, then reflow the part to the board. Here, "high melting point" means significantly higher than the temperature required to reflow the BGA balls. The hope is the bridge stays solid while mounting the part.

Note: I have not done this, so it might not work reliably, or at all. But I work in an IC test lab, and we often try things that might not work when we're in a bind.

Comment: Do you have anything under it? If not you can try this: drill the pad, insert a piece of wire, solder it on the other side to the VIA and cut the other end flush to the board

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions!

Comment: At 0.8mm pitch I’d suggest cutting a groove in the Pcb and dropping a thin wire into it.  I’d bond it in place with a tiny amount of epoxy or cyanoacrylate and then make sure it’s in contact with solder paste at both ends before placing the part.

Comment: Is the VIA through hole? If so, it's easy.

Comment: @Socrates Yes, the via is through hole.

Comment: @pcbguy just put a wire through the hole, solder the hole and bend the end on the pad - it will solder wit hthe paste.

Answer (score 2):

PCBs are cheap nowadays. If you haven't yet assembled (you say bare boards), its probably easier to just respin them.

---

Failing that, if this is for a one-off, and given its a reasonably large pitch BGA, you could try something like the following:

1. Scrape some of the soldermask off the via - say the half of it closest to the two pads that will end up connected. Basically try to keep away from the two pads below which you don't want to risk shorting out to.
2. Onto the via, solder some very thin bare copper wire (e.g. one strand from a multi-stranded wire). Make sure the solder is not too thick that it interferes with the height clearance of the BGA when placed.

   If possible, try to place some of the wire down into the via, as that will help anchor it and stop the surface tension of the reflowing solder from pulling it off the via.
3. Cut the piece of soldered bare wire and position it such that it is just long enough to cross to the far side of the unconnected pad. Don't solder it to the pad, as that would cause excess height on the pad when reflowing the BGA.
4. Apply solder paste to the pads. This should give enough stickyness to hold the piece of wire in place.
5. Reflow the BGA.
6. Hope!

With a bit of look the piece of wire will bond into the reflowed solder balls on the BGA making a decent stable connection. As long as you are careful when placing the BGA not to slide it around, it should cause no problems soldering.